# Is there a way to pass a file as input before i run a pipeline in vsts (File Parameter in VSTS)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is there a way to pass a file as input before i run a pipeline in vsts? . i just want to browse the file from my local desktop (Without checking the file into source control ).

I used to do this as file parameter in jenkins. Trying to do the same in vsts

Note: This is for password file encryption task using ansible (where i can't check in sensitive information file to source control ).

Comment: Ideally, this is not the recommended approach for accessing the secrets/sensitive information through a file (from your local desktop). You need to store the secrets in a secure centralized place like `AzureKeyVault` then you can access the secrets from the vault.

Comment: However it's totally upto you to make a decision, for answering your question. You can try to build your piepline using your own custom agent (instead of hosted agent) then you can refer your local desktop as a network path, then access the file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to see if i can pass a txt file as an input before i run the pipeline .(I mean like file parameter in jenkins)